# Open Mobile Google Search Results in Stack Exchange App

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Is it possible to have Stack Exchange App as a 'generic receiver' for Share intents?

Currently I'm using Dolphin. If I'm searching for something, and one of the search results is a Stack Exchange, I need to first open the Stack Exchange web page, then share the page to Google Keep, then tap on the Google Keep note to have Stack Exchange App 'intercept' the link and open the relevant Q&A.

If the Stack Exchange App can intercept the first or second step above (i.e., directly sharing the search result link, or receiving the shared URL without having to go through Google Keep), it would be a great boon, IMO.